# Java do-while loop continues even though the condition is false

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DealCardsGNN{
public static void main(String[] args){

int numCards = 52;
int CardDealt = 0;

String CardName = "";
String SuitName = "";
char response = ' ';

do{

  while(CardDealt <= numCards){

  int card = (int)(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
  int suit = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

  switch(card){
    case 1: CardName = "Ace"; break;
    case 2: CardName = "2"; break;
    case 3: CardName = "3"; break;
    case 4: CardName = "4"; break;
    case 5: CardName = "5"; break;
    case 6: CardName = "6"; break;
    case 7: CardName = "7"; break;
    case 8: CardName = "8"; break;
    case 9: CardName = "9"; break;
    case 10: CardName = "10"; break;
    case 11: CardName = "Jack"; break;
    case 12: CardName = "Queen"; break;
    case 13: CardName = "King"; break;
    
  }

  switch(suit){
    case 1: SuitName = "Diamonds"; break;
    case 2: SuitName = "Clubs"; break;
    case 3: SuitName = "Hearts"; break;
    case 4: SuitName = "Spades"; break;
  
  }
  
  System.out.println("The card is" + " " + CardName + " " + "of" + " " + SuitName);
  CardDealt++;
  
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Do you want another card? (Enter Y or N)");
  response = scan.next().charAt(0);
  
  
  }

} while(response == 'Y'); 

}
}
```

This program is supposed to simulate dealing cards without using arrays. I wrote a while loop and switch inside a do-while loop that had a condition of the response equaling the character Y. However, the loop repeats even if the condition isn't met. How would I fix this.

Comment: maybe having a correct (consistent) indentation would have helped better *seeing* the problem

Answer (score 3):

### The problem you are experiencing

Note that you have nested loops.

```java
do{
    while(CardDealt <= numCards){
        //...
        response = scan.next().charAt(0);
    }
} while(response == 'Y');
```

So, you are only looping until all cards are dealt and only then checking the response.

Instead, you can integrate the `CardDealt <= numCards` check in the `do while`-loop:

```java
do{
    //...
    response = scan.next().charAt(0);
} while(response == 'Y' && CardDealt <= numCards);
```

This will check the response in each iteration and stop the loop if it isn't `Y`.

### Other issues/improvements

#### re-creating `Scanner`

Also, I would not recommend you to create a new `Scanner` in each iteration. Instead, you can reuse the same scanner throughout your whole program:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//before the loop
do{
    //...
    //also do not create the scanner here
    response = scan.next().charAt(0);
} while(response == 'Y' && CardDealt <= numCards);
```

#### drawing one card too much

As [outlined in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863701/java-do-while-loop-continues-even-though-the-condition-is-false/75863734?noredirect=1#comment133816222_75863734), you are also drawing one card too much by also drawing when 52 cards have already been dealt (this is called in off-by-one error). Instead of `CardDealt <= numCards`, you would need to use `CardDealt < numCards` (only take another card if LESS THAN 52 cards have been taken).

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//before the loop
do{
    //...
    //also do not create the scanner here
    response = scan.next().charAt(0);
} while(response == 'Y' && CardDealt < numCards); //< instead of <= here
```

#### taking cards with repetition

As [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) [mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863701/java-do-while-loop-continues-even-though-the-condition-is-false/75863734?noredirect=1#comment133815810_75863734), your code could pick the same card multiple times.

If you are able to use the collection API (which is unlikely if you cannot use arrays),you can get around that issue by collecting all cards in a list, shuffle it and then remove one each time.

```java
public record Card(String name, String suit){}//or similar
```

then, you can create a list of cards using loops:

```java
List<String> cardNames=List.of("Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",  "Jack", "Queen", "King");
List<String> suitNames=List.of("Diamonds","Clubs","Hearts","Spades");
List<Card> cards=new ArrayList<>();

//go through all combinations of card and suit names
for(String cardName:cardNames){
    for(String suitName:suitNames){
        //add that as a card
        cards.add(new Card(cardName, suitName))
    }
}

//shuffle the list of cards
Collections.shuffle(cards);

//draw a card
//just do this every time you draw a card
int index=cards.size()-1;
Card card=cards.remove(index);

//check whether there are cards left
//!cards.isEmpty()
```

Putting it all together in your code:

```java
List<String> cardNames=List.of("Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",  "Jack", "Queen", "King");
List<String> suitNames=List.of("Diamonds","Clubs","Hearts","Spades");
List<Card> cards=new ArrayList<>();

//go through all combinations of card and suit names
for(String cardName:cardNames){
    for(String suitName:suitNames){
        //add that as a card
        cards.add(new Card(cardName, suitName))
    }
}

//shuffle the list of cards
Collections.shuffle(cards);


char response = ' ';
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
    int index=cards.size()-1;
    Card card=cards.remove(index);
    System.out.println("The card is" + " " + card.name() + " " + "of" + " " + card.suit());
    System.out.println("Do you want another card? (Enter Y or N)");
    response = scan.next().charAt(0);
} while(response == 'Y' && !cards.isEmpty());
```

and in another file:

```java
public record Card(String name, String suit){}
```

Comment: Also checking the number of cards dealt probably does not make much sense right here since  random and independent card is dealt each time. You could easily get 7 of diamonds three times within 52 cards, so that 52 cards are dealt does not mean that the whole deck is dealt.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read that far.

Comment: I addressed these things in my answer now.

Comment: But I thought things like introducing an additional `Queue`/`Deque` is a bit overkill.